# Azure Storage Account SAS and Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I created a linux virtual machine on Azure and a Blob Storage Account on the same subscription and in the same resource group.

I'm trying to access my storage account from my virtual machine using Shared Access Signatures.

So I generated a SAS URL using the public IP of my virtual machine and tried to access the storage account from my Java application and I have an error telling me that the specified IP is not in the range of authorized IPs.

I tried with another subscription and got the same thing.

I tried too using curl and always got the same error.

The error is :

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <Error>
> <Code>AuthorizationSourceIPMismatch</Code>
> <Message>
> This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this source IP 100.**.**.**.
> RequestId:*********-****-****-****-***********
> Time:2016-11-24T09:58:57.9211184Z
> </Message>
> <SourceIP>100.**.**.**</SourceIP>
> </Error>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you provided, I assumed that when you generate the SAS token, you might have configured the optional parameter `IP`.

As mentioned in the official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1):

> IP. An optional parameter that specifies an IP address or a range of IP addresses outside of Azure (see the section Routing session configuration state for Express Route) from which to accept requests.

Please try to check your SAS URL and find whether you have configured the `sip` parameter. You could try to remove the optional IP parameter or include the specific IPs and regenerate your SAS Token.

Comment: Yes I have configured an IP because I need it for security. So I putted the public IP of my Azure Virtual Machine which start as 40.114.*.*.

So the access to the server should work. 

But Azure Storage errors says that the IP that try to access to it starts as 100.*.*.* and that's what I don't understand

Comment: I tried to deploy my web app to a VM and I could access azure storage from my web app back-end by using SAS URL which contains the public IP of my VM. Please try to verify the IP `100.*.*.*` and find out where it came from.

Comment: Apparently it comes from the Azure SNAT. I ask to the Azure support and they try to watch what's happening

Comment: Any updates, please update your question or post an answer for other community members who could experience the same issue.

Comment: The problem came from Azure proxy. If you use Azure proxy, the IP change each time you try to access an external resource.
You need to disable the IP filter from your Azure Storage Account to allow connection from many IP adresses

Comment: The page has been edited. The quote you provide isn't present anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from Bruce, note the same documentation referenced above says "outside of Azure". I would believe then using sip in SAS for IPs in Azure's range would be unsupported. Your best bet for a similar behavior is to use Storage Firewall and allow the VM's virtual network to connect instead.